# Ошибка на вызове окна благодарности после отправки на почту

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, php7

Мне надо было сделать форму отправки, после чего идёт окно благодарности, код лёгкий и примитивный. После отправки страница сразу обновляется, из-за чего окно благодарности не выходит. Php

```
<form class="form_b_4_block" id="contactform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="contactname_1" id="contactname">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше телефон" name="number_1" id="numbers">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit_1" class="button_thanks_1">Расчитать цену</button>
                </form>
<?php
                  if (isset($_POST['contactname_1'])) {$contactname = $_POST['contactname'];}
                  if (isset($_POST['number_1'])) {$number = $_POST['number'];}
                  //Если форма отправлена
                  if(isset($_POST['submit_1'])) {
                    $emailTo = 'ivan-trushko@rambler.ru'; //email
                    $body = "Name: $contactname \n\n Number:\n $number";
                    $subject = "Сообщение с вашего сайта";
                    $headers = "From: My Site Давайте расчитаем стоимость ваших будущих ворот.";
                    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
                  }
                ?>
```

jQ

```
$('.button_thanks_1').click(function (){
      $('.thanks_block').addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: Вы можете сделать отправку аяксом или же в if(isset($_POST['submit_1']))  подставить <script>$('.thanks_block').addClass('active');</script>

Comment: есть такой скрипт, но при отправке сообщения обновляется страница

Comment: Я же вам ответил, если хотите чтобы страница не обновлялась, оставьте форму в одном файле, скрипт перетяните в другой, и при сабмите формы, перехватывайте событие яваскриптом, и отправляйте аяксом запрос к файлу со скриптом, при получении удовлетворительного или не удовлетворительного ответа показываете ваше сообщение.